# Finding A Function That Intersects Polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, optimization

Let's consider the following polynomials
$$P(x, n) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}((-1)^k+k-n)x^k$$
The first six are:

$$P(x, 0) = 1$$
$$P(x, 1) = 2x^{2}-x$$
$$P(x, 2) = 3x^{4}+x^{2}-2x-1$$
$$P(x, 3) = 4x^{6}+x^{5}+2x^{4}-x^{3}-3x-2$$
$$P(x, 4) = 5x^{8}+2x^{7}+3x^{6}+x^{4}-2x^{3}-x^{2}-4x-3$$
$$P(x, 5) = 6x^{10}+3x^{9}+4x^{8}+x^{7}+2x^{6}-x^{5}-3x^{3}-2x^{2}-5x-4$$

plotted in desmos they look like this:

[image]

I'm wondering how one could find a function that intersects all minima $x_0$ of the polynomials.

Obviously there are infinitely many functions that can intersect all six minima of the ones shown, and one can get a fairly good approximation using $y = a-b\tan(x)$ for some $a, b$, however such an approximation wouldnt hold when considering more polynomials $P(x, n)$.

My question is:

Given that
$$P(x, n) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}((-1)^k+k-n)x^k\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall n \geq 0$$

How could one find a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that it intersects all minima $x_0$?

Assuming it is even possible, and what would such a function look like? I appreciate any help!

Comment: The final "$f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: \,\,\,\forall P(x_0, n) \leq P(x, n)\,\,\,$, $x_0 \in f$" is extremely unclear.

Comment: @AnneBauval better?

Comment: I understand your question but I don't think this formula has that meaning, if any.

Comment: Just connect the minima by a sequence of straight lines. Since the minima do not seem to be on a vertical, this will be a continuous function though it will not be derivable. If you want the function to be derivable, then the solution would be to find the coefficients of the 6th degree polynomial passing through the 6 minima.

Comment: @MasB I don't understand what you mean with finding the coefficients of the 6th degree polynomial passing through all six maxima? Wouldn't that just leave us with an approximation as it will not exactly pass through all other minima of $P(x, n)$ for $n > 6$

Comment: @MasB The problem is we don't know the minima, so we cannot connect a sequence of straight lines. That would only give an accurate answer if there was a closed-form equation for all minima

Comment: Of course, you would have to know calculus to find the minima. Once you have them, you can find the equations of the lines joining the minimas two by two.

Comment: This may demonstrate your requirement: The expression is $x+2.7x-\tan\ \left(x+\frac{1}{1.8}\right)^{k}\ \ \left\{-1<x<1\right\}$ for $k=2.1$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oibtbqdefi